# Using MutationObserver in GeckoFx with C#?

Tags: c#, geckofx, mutation-observers

I am using `GeckoFx` to perform a login to a specific website. This website edits the page with new information should the login fail (or require additional authentication, such as a ReCaptcha). Unfortunately, it is vital that I have access an event when the page is updated. I have tried numerous approaches mainly

- A continual check if the `uri` is still the same upon each login attempt and a subsequent check on the specific element in question (to see if the `display: none` property was changed. (This resulted in an infinite loop as it seems `GeckoFx` updates the page in a nonblocking way, causing the program to go into an infinite loop)
- Sleeping for ~5 seconds between login requests and using the aforementioned `uri` check. All this did (predictably, I was grasping at straws) was freeze the browser for 5 seconds and still fail to update the page
- Searching the `GeckoFx` codebase for a specific event when the page is updated similar to the `DocumentCompleted` event (no such luck).

The most common approach I have read about (and one that makes the most sense) is to use a `MutationObserver`. It seems that all of the answers across the internet involve injecting `Javascript` in order to perform the requisite task. Seeing as all of my programming background has not touched web development whatsoever, I'm trying to stick to what I know.

Here is my approach so far, unfortunately, it is not much.

```
public class GeckoTestWebLogin
{
    private readonly string _user;
    private readonly string _pass;
    public GeckoWebBrowser Gweb;
    public Uri LoginUri { get; } = new Uri("https://website.com/login/");

    public bool LoginCompleted { get; private set; } = false;
    public bool Loaded { get; private set; } = false;

    public GeckoTestWebLogin(string user, string pass)
    {
        _user = user;
        _pass = pass;
        Xpcom.EnableProfileMonitoring = false;
        Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");

        //this code is for testing purposes, it will be removed upon project completion
        CookieManager.RemoveAll();

        Gweb = new GeckoWebBrowser();
        Gweb.DocumentCompleted += DocLoaded;

        //right about here is where I get lost, where can I set a callback method for the observer to report back to? Is this even how it works?
        MutationObserver mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(Gweb.Window.DomWindow, (nsISupports)Gweb.Document.DomObject);
    }

    private void TestObservedEvent(string parms, object[] objs)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The page was changed @ " + DateTime.Now);
    }

    public void DocLoaded(object obj, GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded = true;
        if (Gweb.Url != LoginUri) return;
        AttemptLogin();
    }

    private void AttemptLogin()
    {
        GeckoElementCollection elements = Gweb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (GeckoHtmlElement element in elements)
        {
            switch (element.Id)
            {
                case "username":
                    element.SetAttribute("value", _user);
                    break;
                case "password":
                    element.SetAttribute("value", _pass);
                    break;
                case "importantchangedinfo":
                    GeckoHtmlElement authcodeModal =
                        (GeckoHtmlElement)
                            Gweb.Document.GetElementsByClassName("login_modal").First();
                    if (authcodeModal.Attributes["style"].NodeValue != "display: none")
                    {
                        InputForm form = new InputForm { InputDescription = "Captcha Required!" };
                        form.ShowDialog();
                        elements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "captchabox")?.SetAttribute("value", form.Input);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        elements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "Login")?.Click();
    }

    public void Login()
    {
        //this will cause the DocLoaded event to fire after completion
        Gweb.Navigate(LoginUri.ToString());
    }
}
```

As stated in the above code in the comments, I am completely lost at

```
MutationObserver mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(Gweb.Window.DomWindow, (nsISupports)Gweb.Document.DomObject);
```

I can't seem to find anything in `GeckoFx`'s source for `MutationObserver` that would allow me to set a callback/event/whathaveyou. Is my approach the correct way to go about things or am I left with no options other than to inject `Javascript` into the page?

Much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Here is my attempt at option 2 in Tom's answer:

(Added into GeckoTestWebLogin)

```
    public void DocLoaded(object obj, GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded = true;
        if (Gweb.Url != LoginUri) return;

        MutationEventListener mutationListener = new MutationEventListener();
        mutationListener.OnDomMutation += TestObservedEvent;
        nsIDOMEventTarget target = Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsIDOMEventTarget>(/*Lost here*/);
        using (nsAString modified = new nsAString("DOMSubtreeModified"))
            target.AddEventListener(modified, mutationListener, true, false, 0);

        AttemptLogin();
    }
```

MutationEventListener.cs:

```
public delegate void OnDomMutation(/*DomMutationArgs args*/);

public class MutationEventListener : nsIDOMEventListener
{
    public event OnDomMutation OnDomMutation;

    public void HandleEvent(nsIDOMEvent domEvent)
    {
        OnDomMutation?.Invoke(/*new DomMutationArgs(domEvent, this)*/);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Geckofx's [webidl compiler](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/webidltogeckofxbindings) is currently advanced enough to generate the callback constructor.

Option 1. - Enhance MutationObserver source.

You could modify MutationObserver source manually to add the necessary constructor callback. Then recompile Geckofx. (I haven't look to see how difficult this is)

Option 2. - Use old style Mutation events.

```
public class DOMSubtreeModifiedEventListener : nsIDOMEventListener
{
     ... // Implement HandleEvent 
}
```

Then something like (maybe in DocumentCompleted event handler):

```
    _domSubtreeModifiedEventListener = new DOMSubtreeModifiedEventListener(this);

    var target = Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsIDOMEventTarget>(body);
    using (nsAString subtreeModified = new nsAString("DOMSubtreeModified"))
        target.AddEventListener(subtreeModified, _domSubtreeModifiedEventListener, true, false, 0);
```

Option 3. - Use Idle + Check.

Add an winforms Application.idle event handler - and examine the document, to know when its ready.

Option 4. - Inject a javascript callback.

(As you have already mentioned) - This example is waiting until after a resize is done.

basically inject: `"<body onresize=fireResizedEventAfterDelay()>"` : then inject something like this:

```
 string fireResizedEventAfterDelayScript = "<script>\n" +
            "var resizeListner;" +
            "var msDelay = 20;" +
            "function fireResizedEventAfterDelay() {" +
            "clearTimeout(resizeListner);" +
            "resizeListner = setTimeout(function() { document.dispatchEvent (new MessageEvent('resized')); }, msDelay);" +
            "}\n" +
            "</script>\n";
```

Then in the C#:

```
browser.AddMessageEventListener("resized", (s) => runafterImDone())
```

Comment: Hello, I was attempting option 2, however, the only appropriate reference I could find for `var target = Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsIDOMEventTarget>(X);` was `WindowRoot` in `Window.cs`. However, it would seem that while  `GeckoWindow.cs` extends `Window.cs`, it does not expose the aforementioned `WindowRoot` property. Am I going about this the incorrect way? I have included the relevant parts of my attempt in my original question.

Comment: var body = browser.Document?.Body?.DOMHtmlElement;